# How do users give me permission to access their Gmail inbox?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

How can I make it possible on my website for users can give me read access to their Gmail inbox? And can I access his emails using Google Apis?

Comment: When you register your application with Google (to be able to use the APIs) you select what operations you want to be allowed to perform. When the user authenticates they authorise your app to use those APIs against their account. At that point, you can use tokens from the authentiction/authorisation process to access their mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

Users must enable Pop or Imap on their gmail account by going on "Settings -> POP/IMAP Forwarding". Then they must give you their access credentials.
You can build your client to read emails from third party services, and use their credentials to access their emails. I saw a tag about asp, so take a look here https://www.example-code.com/asp/imap.asp

Comment: There are also a lot of packages that do hard work for you and let you easily build your own mail client. Just google "imap library" for programming language that you are using